# JESD204 ADC - fiber optic?

Tags: fpga, adc, interface, optoelectronics

There's a Youtube video of a high speed ADC, using JESD204 high speed interface, interfacing with an FPGA via a fiber-optic transceiver:  http://youtu.be/vkrms2udeKI

Is there a commercial version of this? Are there any papers, Tech Notes, etc. discussing the problems [speed, distance, number of fibers etc] involved in creating such a link?

In the area I'm considering, the optic fiber runs would be up to 5 kilometres...

Comment: Alan, This was a while back... but yes. This is possible since JESD204/B is a great candidate for comms via fiber. A project I'm working on uses 8 channel JESD204B at 8Gbps converts it to optical signals with an SFP/SFP+ and uses a mux/demux (WDMA). The signal processing is done 10km away... for thermal/access purposes. Did you try this? Any feedback is good.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As per the other answer, I have to ask: what mode fibre / transceivers are you using? I'd have thought the companies selling JESD204 components would include this in all their sample designs, to hype the noise isolation benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Good single mode fiber has a loss of around 0.2 dB per kilometer.  Generally, fiber optic transceivers of this sort have a link budget of around 10-15 dB, so you can put about 50 km of fiber between them and still be within the loss budget.  You have to make sure that you're using the right transceivers, though.  The long range stuff is all single mode, 1550 nm.  THe module in the video you linked looks like it might be an multimode, 850nm SFP module.  These modules are very cheap, but you would be lucky to go even a km with that.  Note that this has more to do with intersymbol interference due to the difference in mode propagation speeds than the overall loss in the fiber.

You might want to look at 1G and 10G Ethernet and Fibre Channel for more information about long distance fiber optic connections, as these are just different serial protocols that can be transmitted over fiber.